# Permutations + Combinations Proof

Tags: probability, proof-writing, permutations, combinations, probability-limit-theorems

$W_n^{(k)}$ is the number of permutations in a set of all $n!$ permutations in a $n$-element set which has $k$ fixed points.

$W_n^{(0)}$ is the number of n-derangements where  $\frac{W_n}{n!} \rightarrow \frac{1}{e}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

I need to show that $$W_n^{(k)}={{n}\choose{k}} \cdot W_{n-k}$$

From this formula, I should be able to show, the probability that a random
permutation in a set of all n! permutations in an $n$-element set which has $k$ fixed points converges to $\frac{1}{e \cdot k!}$

This is my attempt so far:

Since $W_n^{(k)}$ is just # of permutation of n elements with k fixed points, we can say $W_n^{(k)} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$. Then the number of distinct subsets with k elements that can be chosen from a set with n elements is $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \equiv$ ${{n}\choose{k}}$

So now, I attempt to try multiplying $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \cdot W_{n-k}$ and try to find the limit of it. But what is $W_{n-k}$? Any ideas, tips ,help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of permutations with exactly $k$ fixed points is $\binom{n}{k}$ times the number of derangements of $n-k$ objects. You know that for fixed $k$ and large $n$ the number of derangements of $n-k$ objects  behaves like $(n-k)!\cdot \frac{1}{e}$.

The above paragraph can be summarized in symbols as follows:
$$\frac{W_n^{(k)}}{n!}=\frac{1}{n!}\binom{n}{k}(n-k)!\frac{W_{n-k}^{(0)}}{(n-k)!}.$$

The product of the first three terms on the right simplifies to $\frac{1}{k!}$, and the last term has limit $\frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: Mind explaining why  multiply $\frac{1}{n!}$

Comment: I could have written down the equation $W_n^{(k)}=\binom{n}{k}W_{n-k}^{(0)}$ (no $1/n!$). But you are interested in the limit of $W_n^{(k)}/n!$,  so I divided by $n!$ on both sides, and also did a multiplication and division by $(n-k)!$ on the right to make it easier for you to calculate the limit.